# What was the purpose of deleting my answer to the Cyrus cylinder question?

Tags: discussion

I answered this question about Cyrus cylinder:
https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7875/are-there-other-ancient-human-rights-surely-in-its-ancient-consept-documents-l

The answer was the most upvoted.

The content of the answer is as follows:

===

Of course it was not a human rights document. At best it is a code of laws, which can be seen as a summary of civil rights.

Civil rights should not be confused with human rights as human rights are construed to belong to all people, including slaves, foreigners and defeated enemy.

**Update**

This is the [full text of the Cyrus cylinder](http://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/articles/c/cyrus_cylinder_-_translation.aspx). Contrary to my previous speculation, it is not a code of laws. The text does not do anything with the rights of anybody.

The first part of the document is in the third person.

- The first part denigrates the previous kings of Babylon, especially their religious practices, halting the offerings and the like.
- The Gods disliking this previous king decided to choose a better one, whom they decided should be Cyrus.
- Then follows the part where it is described how much the people and subordinated kings love Cyrus and kiss his feet.

The second part is explained from the name of Cyrus himself:

- The full title of Cyrus
- Cyrus describes that his troops entered Babylon peacefully (following the city's surrender) and made no damage to the population and temples.
- Again how much the subordinated kings and representatives of remote quarters expressed love and loyalty to him and kissed his feet.
- He then describes how he restored and rebuilt the temples.
- He then describes how he improved the defenses and city walls.

The claim that it has something about "human rights" is described as a hoax, for example, [by Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/international/world/falling-for-ancient-propaganda-un-treasure-honors-persian-despot-a-566027-2.html).

===

It is well sourced. What is the purpose of deleting?

Comment: Is deleting the answer because the topic starter disagrees with it a correct policy?

Comment: Are you really sure about most upvoted answer? I found only 2 votes that is clearly obvious they are coming from which users! I am sorry that it seems some users are trying revenge play here against each other! Take a look at the question and if you found a better answer I will promise you accept it. I do not used to attack in shadows and leave the matter in darkness. Only please control your feelings!

Comment: Aha! It seems you have prejudiced followers here who after any wrong or weird reaction by you as an answer or comment give you a gift  by an upvote! So I do not know why you are unsatisfied again! There are some who make neutral my positive votes by giving a negative vote and doing the opposite about you! An interesting fairness! So be relax and count your votes and be happy about your knowledge in history! ;))

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I made a mistake. I meant to close the question, but that has been rectified. If you two are going to turn this site into your own debate forum, I will shut down both of your accounts. Take it to the chat forum and stop attacking each other in comments. Otherwise you will both find a LOT of questions and answers getting deleted and/or closed.

Comment: Please tell me whom did I attack and where?

Comment: The language and dialog between you and user37324 has gotten completely out of hand, and it won't be tolerated. Some of your discussions have devolved into verbal attacks, so I am trying to stop it now before it escalates.

Comment: what are the attacks from my side? I tried to maintain coolness.

Comment: Go back and look at some of your comments. You have a tendedncy to "bait" people into debates, just as you are doing with me. This type of behavior is unacceptable, and future comments of this nature will be deleted. In fact, some already have been.

Comment: I think there is a tendency to send off topic answers too and get positive votes by a friend. So i am wondering how voting can be a sign of democracy in cyber spaces? everybody can misuse it by creating multiple IDs or getting help of some friends against another one.

Comment: @user37324 creating multiple ids and voting on your own posts is against the rules and there are many systems in place to catch it (and they are very good at it). There are also scripts in place to detect and reverse serial voting by others, if you feel the scripts are missing something you can try explaining in a flag, but this is far harder to correct.